JBL Link20 Mainboard - A25P 78 component
I have a question, really need your help here please. Trying to identify what component is this from the mainboard TXC-M E250336 which belongs to a JBL Link20. It has A25P 78 marked on it. I have tried to do my research but still not sure if this is a voltage detector or Zener diode. Thank you.



It looks like a SOT-23. Could you confirm ?

For a SOT-23 footprint there are numerous hits, such as : CAZ23C3V0 Zener diode, ELM9725NBB Voltage detector, KIC77A25T Voltage detector, LN2351P3612M DC/DC voltage converter, XC31PNS0025AM Linear voltage regulator mostly.

Hey, yes it's a SOT-23, but not sure how to check if it's a Zener diode or voltage detector. Thank you

You can use a multimeter to check for a forward voltage drop of about 0,6V. Most good multimeters have diode checking settings. So you could do that. The CAZ23C3V0 is a dual diode. Check the datasheet to see if it's a common-anode or cathode etc...

Thank you! Let me check it
